# Some font awesome brands don't work (show square) event though other work fine

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm loading this script as css:

> https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook export-brands"></i>
<i class="fa fa-smile export-brands"></i>
```

The result is the following:

[image]

I've tried loading the css locally, different versions, I've tried the js version, same problem (different not found logo).

The chrome dev tools show

```
.fa-facebook:before {
    content: "\f09a";
}
```

As it should when I checked the source css.

Don't know what else to try.

Comment: here is no more `fa` you should use `fab` for the brand icon

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NYENRG , after adding fontawesome cdn , it shows fine - https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: `The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the fas solid style and the fab style for brands.` --> https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js

Comment: @NagaSaiA this is the V4 it's about the V5 here

Comment: @TemaniAfif it worked with `fab`!

Comment: changing from fa to fab shows icon fine  - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QmJNvE

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you want to post as an answer?

Comment: well am pretty sure there is a duplicate but not able to find it :)

Comment: got it ;) you may found more information in the dup also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the Font Awesome 5 stylesheet with Font Awesome 4 syntax. The problem can be fixed in one of two ways:

1. Load a stylesheet for an older version, or preferably
2. Double check your class names and be sure to [use the current standard](https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-f?style=brands).

Answer (score -1):

Possibly due to Adblock blocking some "brand" icons?

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#some-brand-icons-are-missing

Comment: good bet, but no, I disabled ublock just to be sure. it's not that. thanks! (not my down-vote, thanks for trying)